# Visual Studio media queries not working as intended

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have been working on a project to make a site responsive. But there is one big problem. The `@media` tag is not working as it should.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 873px){/* lots of css in here */}
```

and the other media-query

```
@media screen and (min-width: 874px){/* lots of css in here */}
```

[image: media-query view google-chrome]

As you can see in the img above the media queries are shown in pixels. So far its working as intended.

The query should activate when the pixels fall under 873px.

[image: not working query]

As you can see in the image above the pixels are under 873 but the style rules are not adjusted. When we type in the console:

```
$(document).width()  ( with the pixels on 873px)( window instead of document does the same)
```

we get 1141.

When the pixels are put on 656 the style rules for above 873 are still active.
But when we drop by 1 pixel to 655 the style rules for under 873 are active.

[image: pixels under 655]

When we type in the console $(document).width() we get 925.

I am not sure what causes this problem because other sites, that are not build in Visual Studio, don't have this problem( and the pixels match the `$(document).width()` ).

Does anybody know what the problem is and how to fix it?

Comment: Did you refresh after changing the window size?

Comment: Yes we did, and it still stays the same(not as intended).

Comment: Show your CSS file (complete, possible there is an syntax error in it, so it doesn't render correctly). Or validate it yourself https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Comment: Just took a look at the beta domain. CSS looks fine, add something different between the two media queries(red background for example), to make sure your chrome debugger isn't wrong. [EDIT] Firefox shows the correct line, looks like a Chrome bug